# How can I avoid blocking a discord python bot when the await function call takes more than 10 seconds?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this issue with my discord python bot where I am using a task that runs every 5 minutes. This task awaits another function called `check_all`, this function can sometimes take some time to run and so I keep getting the following warning:

```
WARNING  discord.gateway Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds.
```

I think the solution can be to make the discord task start some process as another thread which will then notify the bot when it is done and have it send a message containing the result of this problematic function call but I couldn't figure out how to do that so I would love some hints to point me in the right direction or a solution for this issue.

This is the concerned code snippet:

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def send_message():
  channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name="bremen")
  current_time = datetime.now(BerlinTz)
  formatted_time = current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  await channel.send(f'{formatted_time}: Checking all cities ...')
  response = await check_all()
  formatted_output = format_data(response)
  await channel.send(formatted_output)
```

Looking forward to the replies!!

I tried using asyncio to create a task but couldn't figure out how to have this task notify the bot somehow after it is finished.

Comment: If `check_all` is the problem, it would be helpful to see that part of the code

Comment: It's basically running selenium to check for some conditions on a website. Accessing it requires clicking on a few button hence why selenium is used and not some other web scraping library.